# BeanShell Post Processor parse Json using Jmeter

Tags: json, rest, jmeter, beanshell

I need to test rest api posting Json.
I try to post Json Data by BeanShell PostProcessor using Jmeter. 
But BeanShell PostProcessor doesn't work or I couldn't write the right code.

My Json is : {"email":"selin@xxx.com","password":"123"}

You can see in the pictures below what i did.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you wanted to make an http request on an api.
Follow this steps.

1. Open a new instance of JMeter
2. Under Test Plan, add a HTTP Header Manager to set the content type by navigating to Test Plan > Add > Config Element > HTTP Header Manager. Add new value for Name = “Content-Type” and value = “application/json” (without quotes).
3. Under Test Plan, add a thread group by navigating to Test Plan > Add > Threads (Users) > Thread Group
4. Under Thread Group, add a sampler of type HTTP Request by navigating to Thread Group > Add > Sampler > HTTP Request
5. You can add various listeners to the Thread Group. I prefer Results in Table/Tree by navigating to Thread Group > Add > Listener > View Results in Table

You can add JSON data manully like shown on the picture.

[image: JMeter Http Request Parameters]

[There is a gist also](https://gist.github.com/86d5fb1de82ed72289e1)

[This gist includes BeanShell Post Processor Version](https://gist.github.com/1fc5e1b42cd74b26d537)

Comment: Thank you very much engincancan! It works for me! But I still need to use beanshell post processor. :)

Comment: I added the BeanShell version to the gist. Please check the second link. :)

Comment: Thank you engincancan!! It works! I am really happy! I couldn't think that would be very simple.

Answer (score 1):

in.

There is a couple of problems with your Beanshell Sampler code:

1. In Beanshell you need to escape quotation marks with slash like `\"`
2. [SampleResult.setResponseData](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData(byte%5B%5D)) method accepts byte array, not string.

So if you amend your Beanshell Sampler code as follows:

```
String dummyJson = "{\"email\":\"selin@xxx.com\",\"password\":\"123\"}";
SampleResult.setResponseData(dummyJson.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

everything should be fine from Beanshell perspective.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed BeanShell sampler code like you said. But i am still getting error, I think my BeanShell PostPocessor code has problem.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of what you need to send, but. 1. where `getJSONObject` method is defined? 2. Your "Dummy Post Request" server IP/Name section is empty. 3. Path should start from `/`

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Ralf Sternberg’s slim JSON parser for Java](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/)  as it is described [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/).

This is maven dependency of it's current version:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.eclipsesource.minimal-json</groupId>
     <artifactId>minimal-json</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to add this library to Jemeter's lib directory.